# Directly casting from pointer to a template function?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am trying to take a pointer to an instance of function template and cast it to void*:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void plainFunction(int *param) {}

template <typename T>
void templateFunction(T *param) {}

int main() {
    void *addr1=&plainFunction; //OK
    void *addr2=&templateFunction<int>; //Compile error
}
```

I get the following error (in Visual Studio 2008)

```
main.cu(10) : error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'void (__cdecl *)(T *)' to 'void *'
Context does not allow for disambiguation of overloaded function
```

Why is it happening? Function `templateFunction` (for concrete type `T=int`) is not overloaded. It is possible to deduct which instance of the function I am refering to.

If I replace the erroneus line with:

```
void (*foo)(int*)=&templateFunction<int>;
void *addr2=foo;
```

It compiles without a problem.

Thank you!

---

*Update:*

When normal pointer `void*` is replaced by dummy function pointer `void(*)()`, as suggested by James (thank you), it makes the error go away:

```
void (*addr1)()=(void(*)())&plainFunction;
void (*addr2)()=(void(*)())(&templateFunction<int>);
```

However, if the error was caused by casting a function-pointer to a normal pointer, the compiler should complain in both cases. It does not however, so I continue to assume that it is correct at least for this compiler. If I am not mistaken, the standard just says that function pointers don't *have to* be represented like normal pointers, but it does not forbid that.

Comment: Concerning your update, it doesn't matter whether pointers to functions and pointers to objects have the same size and representation:  conversion from a function pointer to `void*` is simply not allowed.  Note that with your update, you can't call either of the functions through a `void(*)()` because that isn't the type of either function; you would have to cast `addr1` or `addr2` back to the correct type (`void(*)(int*)`) to make the call, otherwise the behavior is undefined.

Comment: What I really need is a "function entry point" which is later passed to CUDA library. The function, I am actually taking pointer to never even exists as CPU-executable piece of code, it resides on GPU. I just stripped of CUDA-specific stuff to make my example as simple as possible and get some input from people who work with C++ but not necessairly with CUDA. And I was not mistaken to do so - your answer opened my eyes on the aspect of function pointers that I was not aware of, despite using them many times already. Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Both are technically wrong:  in C++, you can't convert a function pointer to a `void*`.

Pointer-to-function types (like `void (*)(int*)` here) are a completely different class of types than pointer-to-object types (like `void*` here).

Visual C++ allowing the conversion at all (e.g. in `void* addr1 = &plainFunction;`) is a language extension (compiling with the `/Za` flag, which disables language extensions, causes both lines to be rejected).

The error is a bit misleading, for sure, though some other compilers are equally unhelpful (Comeau reports "error: no instance of function template "templateFunction" matches the required type").

Comment: You are right, although usually function pointers _can_ be casted to normal function. Correcting the question to match the standard.

Comment: @CygnusX1:  I'm not sure I understand your comment.  As you've demonstrated, Visual C++ _does_ allow you to assign the address of a function template instantiation to a function pointer.

Comment: Because I meant "You are right, although usually function pointers can be casted to normal **pointers**". My fault. Sorry. I think one thing and write another.

Answer (score 6):

Compiler should generate error in both cases. Function pointers are not convertible to `void`* according to the Standard §4.10/2 since functions are not objects (§1.8/1). Visual Studio 2008 allows this as an extension, check [this bug](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/425547).

Use `typedef` to avoid misunderstanding:

```
typedef void(func)(int*); // declare func type
func* addr1 = &plainFunction;         // OK
func* addr2 = &templateFunction<int>; // OK
```

Comment: Oh. So you say, casting to `void*` is _against_ the standard and not that its merely "doesn't have to, but may"?

Comment: "are not convertible" means that Standard forbids that. VS2008 is not Standard conformant compiler. You shouldn't use that bug in VS2008 if you want to keep your code portable.

Comment: I didn't know it is actually a bug. Now I know. Thank you.