# How to pass the address of a template kernel function to a CUDA function?

Tags: templates, cuda

I want to use CUDA runtime API functions accepting CUDA kernel function pointers with kernel templates.

I am able to do the following without templates:

```
__global__ myKernel()
{
  ...
}

void myFunc(const char* kernel_ptr)
{
  ...
  // use API functions like
  cudaFuncGetAttributes(&attrib, kernel_ptr);
  ...
}

int main()
{
  myFunc(myKernel);
}
```

However the above does not work when the kernel is a template.

Another example:

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <stdio.h>

template<typename T>
__global__ void addKernel(T *c, const T *a, const T *b)
{
    int i = threadIdx.x;
    c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
}

int main()
{
    cudaFuncAttributes attrib;
    cudaError_t err;

    //OK:
    err = cudaFuncGetAttributes(&attrib, addKernel<float>); // works fine
    printf("result: %s, reg1: %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(err), attrib.numRegs);

    //NOT OK:
    //try to get function ptr to pass as an argument:
    const char* ptr = addKernel<float>; // compile error
    err = cudaFuncGetAttributes(&attrib, ptr);
    printf("result: %s, reg2: %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(err), attrib.numRegs);
}
```

The above results in a compile error:

> error : no instance of function template "addKernel" matches the
>   required type

Edit:
The only workaround I've found so far is to put the stuff inside myFunc (see first code example) into a macro, which is ugly, but it requires no pointer argument passing and it works fine:

```
#define MY_FUNC(kernel) \
  { \
     ...\
     cudaFuncGetAttributes( &attrib, kernel ); \
     ...\
  }
```

Usage:

```
MY_FUNC( myKernel<float> )
```

Comment: Edited code example with error handling, in case someone might want to try and play with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referring to your code contained in "another example:"

change this:

```
const char* ptr = addKernel<float>; // compile error
```

to this:

```
void (*ptr)(float *, const float *, const float *) = addKernel<float>;
```

And I believe it will compile and run correctly.

I don't know if it's useful or not in the overall scope of what you are trying to do.

**EDIT** responding to a question in the comments:

Once I have the pointer "extracted" from the function, I can then cast it to another type.  Try it.  For example, the following code also works:

```
void (*ptr)(float *, const float *, const float *) = addKernel<float>;
const char *ptr1 = (char *)ptr;
err = cudaFuncGetAttributes(&attrib, ptr1);
```

So, to answer your question, you *can* cast your function pointer to `const char*` if you want to, once you have your function pointer.

By the way, the code you posted as an answer throws compile errors for me on gcc 4.1.2 and gcc 4.4.6:

```
$ nvcc -arch=sm_20 -O3 -o t201 t201.cu
t201.cu: In function âint main()â:
t201.cu:25: error: address of overloaded function with no contextual type information
t201.cu:29: error: address of overloaded function with no contextual type information
$
```

And I get errors also if I remove the `&` in those two lines:

```
$ nvcc -arch=sm_20 -O3 -o t201 t201.cu
t201.cu: In function âint main()â:
t201.cu:25: error: insufficient contextual information to determine type
t201.cu:29: error: insufficient contextual information to determine type
$
```

So some of this may be compiler dependent, in terms of what steps are needed to get from point A to point B.

Comment: Same as Jared's answer.  I guess he posted while I was still editing/thinking on my answer.

Comment: This works indeed, however, there is a thing I still don't get.
The second argument of cudaFuncGetAttributes is const char* in cuda_runtima_api.h. There is also a templated version in cuda_runtime.h, but in the function definition, it is just a cast to (const char*). So why am I not able to cast my funtion pointer to const char* and pass it to my fundtion while cuda is seemingly able to do it?

Comment: Ok, based on the solution of you two, I was able to find a generic solution using this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5277547/directly-casting-from-pointer-to-a-template-function
So a void function pointer does it: void (*ptr)() = (void(*)())(&addKernel<float>);

Comment: I've accepted Jared's answer, as I deducted from the comments he was the first who gave the right solution. I'd be still glad if someone could provide the answer how CUDA does this using const char*.

Comment: Now this is weird: for me, using Visual Studio 2010, it works with or without the '&'s using the /Za option which disables Microsoft specific language extensions.

Comment: I accepted your answer as it now provides more details about the question.

Answer (score 2):

The type of `addKernel<void>` is not `char *`, it's a function type.

Instead, get the address of `addKernel<float>` like this:

```
typedef void (*fun_ptr)(float*,const float *, const float*);
fun_ptr ptr = addKernel<float>; // compile error
err = cudaFuncGetAttributes(&attrib, ptr);
```

Comment: I added a comment to Robert's answer (as it was the first in the list), which is related to your solution as well.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: added a templated version based on cuda runtime and the answer of Robert Crovella.

Here is a full working example using void function pointers and templates.

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <stdio.h>

template <typename T>
__global__ void addKernel(T *c, const T *a, const T *b)
{
    int i = threadIdx.x;
    c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
}

cudaError_t func1( cudaFuncAttributes* attrib, void (*ptr)() )
{
    return cudaFuncGetAttributes(attrib, ptr);
}

cudaError_t func2( cudaFuncAttributes* attrib, const char* ptr )
{
    return cudaFuncGetAttributes(attrib, ptr);
}

template <typename T>
cudaError_t func2( cudaFuncAttributes* attrib, T ptr )
{
    return func2( attrib, (const char*) ptr);
}

int main()
{
    cudaFuncAttributes attrib;
    cudaError_t err;

    void (*ptr2)() = (void(*)())(addKernel<float>);  // OK on Visual Studio
    err = func1(&attrib, ptr2);
    printf("result: %s, reg1: %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(err), attrib.numRegs);

    err = func2(&attrib, addKernel<double> ); // OK nice and standard
    printf("result: %s, reg2: %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(err), attrib.numRegs);
}
```